# Selecting from selection based on attribute table in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, select

I selected polygons which are less than 313 m2 and from that selection I need to select the ones that are completely within some other polygon. 
So, both selections are on the same shapefile.

I tried selection by attribute and by location which seems to respond.

Answer (score 4):

You may use [Select Layer by Location](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/select-layer-by-location.htm) many times on the same layer.  Just make sure the selection type option is set to ADD_TO_SELECTION for your case.

> ADD_TO_SELECTION —The resulting selection is added to an existing
>   selection, if one exists. If no selection exists, this is the same as
>   the NEW_SELECTION option.

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right way. You can use select-by-location to select the features desired. Here is a tutorial on how to do it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fVxbBAy_oFE

Comment: Thanks for response. But they use to have more than one layer to select, whereas I need only select from one layer.

Comment: You can add another instance of the shapefile and perform the select.

Comment: The initial issue was to merge polygons that have area smaller than 1250 m2 to the larger polygons which surround them, based on the boundary sharing. For instance, the smaller polygon shares more boundary to the ‘A’ polygon than the ‘B’ polygon (which are both the neighbors of the small polygon) then it should be merged to the polygon which shares the boundary the most, which is ‘A’ in this case.

Comment: Coming from this point of view, I selected polygons which are smaller than 1250 m2 and the next step is to find out the boundary sharing of neighboring polygons and based on that merge smaller polygons to them. It is like “Rich gets richer, and poor gets pooper.”
I think, initially I might be on the wrong track, which led to the wrong question I asked, initially.

Thanks for reply.